# Detect HDMI Port in android device

Tags: android, hdmi

I am working on a Android development app that needs to detect HDMI Port. Can some one guide me how can i detect HDMI port in andorid device programatically.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This link has some information on the topic which you mentioned: http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/how-to-use-the-hidden-hdmi-api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to listen to the broadcast hidden android intent

```
"android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED"
```

if you use android 4.0 or higher or if you use Sony device:

```
"com.sonyericsson.intent.action.HDMI_EVENT"
```

Check this tutorial for more information: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/05/29/how-to-use-the-hidden-hdmi-api-tutorial/

There are also 3rd party libraires like KernelSwitchObserverLib
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1963785

Comment: KernelSwitchObserver causes an exception for Samsung S4 with Andriod 4.2.2 since the last Samsung Hotfix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788742/unable-to-open-socket-for-ueventobserver-exception#comment27705096_18788742.