# Unable to open socket for UEventObserver Exception

Tags: android

since a few days we observe a rapid increase of an unnusual exception when the user uses our app with the **Samsung S4** (the error does not appear on other devices).

We could not determine the source of the exception but got two indications:

- The exception message from the user:

  ```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open socket for UEventObserver
  at android.os.UEventObserver.nativeSetup(Native Method)
  at android.os.UEventObserver.access$000(UEventObserver.java:41)
  at android.os.UEventObserver$UEventThread.run(UEventObserver.java:179)
  ```
- A dialog with the title `Prevention information` appears after the app has crashed.
  [image: Screenshot]
  Updating the policy ends with the error message `Update failed due to network issues`.

After a google search i found the information that there are other apps like **whats app** with the same issue but unfortunately without solutions.

Does anyone know this issue or a solution for this problem?

Comment: A bit more context would be nice. That warning message mentions an "unauthorized installation route". How do you deploy your app and the updates? Do you let your app update itself automatically?

Comment: Deployment and updates are managed by the google developer console. I may have missed to say that some users are reporting that the app crashes after setup and other are reporting that the app crashes after a few minutes usage (with the same exception). Sorry for the lack of information but that is everything i have.

Comment: I found a related thread here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2430313 which mentions that some app causes that problem by trying to get root access on a rooted device. Could you get in touch with some users who reported that problem and ask them if their device is rooted and what root-capable apps are installed?

Comment: Thanks, i found the exception with the help of your hint. I am using an external lib to check the devices hdmi state (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1963785). This lib is causing the problem. Now i have to look for another way to check the hdmi state as long as google do not share this information through the api